# Upgrade 7.5 to 9 - Content type ImageFile is not allowed to be created under parent of content type SysContentAssetFolder

Tags: episerver

I've upgraded an EPiServer CMS site from 7.5 to 9, upgrading source code and DB. I don't necessarily need to migrate the Media files.

After the upgrade, everything looks to be working fine, except when I try to add images, documents or try to create blocks.

When adding an image for a page, it fails with the following error: *Content type "ImageFile" is not allowed to be created under parent of content type "SysContentAssetFolder"*.

When I try to add a global Content Block, none of the block types appear. When trying to add it in a content area, there is no button to add new ones.

I've found that if I explicitly allow the Content Type (ImageFile or the content block) under a page type in the tblContentTypeToContentType table, it works. Nevertheless I don't think that the right approach would be to add permissions one per one. We didn't need to in version 7.5.

Hope someone can help with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't set any restrictions with `AllowedContentTypes`  somewhere? For example on ImageFile?

Comment: No, there are no restrictions set whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround for now, by inserting the following records:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblContentTypeToContentType] ([fkContentTypeParentID],[fkContentTypeChildID],[Access],[Availability],[Allow])
VALUES (3,3,2,2,null) -- for SysContentFolder


INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblContentTypeToContentType] ([fkContentTypeParentID],[fkContentTypeChildID],[Access],[Availability],[Allow])
VALUES (4,4,2,2,null) -- for SysContentAssetFolderNevertheless
```

I'm not sure this is the correct fix, and if it could have unwanted consecuences.